# Programmatically creating a new DB in Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to programmatically create a database in Spring Boot then put it as an active data source.

Is such a thing even possible? I see all this dynamic changing of the DBs, but that's not what I need and I can't find any information on this in the documentation, only about migrations, DB initialization etc.

Using spring boot 1.3.1 with PostgreSQL 9.4 DB.

Comment: By programmatically you mean create it at application startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute the sql statement to create a database:

```
 CREATE DATABASE name;
```

or in the case you need the database owns to a user:

```
 CREATE DATABASE name OWNER username TABLESPACE tablespacename;
```

---

Then use `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to add the new datasource and change it to it.

- https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: I'll have to try this out, didn't occur to me that I could have a migration with `CREATE DATABASE` :).

Comment: I managed to do it sort of like this. We're using Flyway in our project, so I could run statements in Flyway Callbacks, then switch my DataSource from there as well (no need for `AbstractRoutingDataSource`). Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot allows you to keep sql files in class path.These files are used to created Database initialization. 
you can use it from here [Spring Boot Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)